# How would I listen for a LongClick on an overlay item in a Google MapView?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm a novice Android monkey and I've hit a snag trying to implement a feature on my app. What I want to do is have my users be able to long click an overlay item (it's a bus stop) and add that marker (stop number and address) to their favorites tab. The problem is... how do I listen for and handle a long click(tap) on an overlay item??

Currently I'm @overriding the onTap function in my Overlay class to handle regular taps, but I don't see an onLongTap function to override in the documentation... Can anyone set me along the right path? Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks for reading this

P.S. This is my first SO question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to override [`onTouchEvent(MotionEvent, MapView)`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29) for more complex user interactions. For a 'long' tap, you should start some sort of timer that will indicate how long the user has been pressing on a specific Overlay item. Once a certain threshold is reached - I believe the default delay for a 'long' press is roughly 1500 ms - you then execute the relevant code.

Alternatively, you could take a look at including the [mapview-overlay-manager](http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/) project, which, from the reads of it, should offer exactly what your looking for (and then some):

> **OnOverlayGestureListener**
>
> Simplified OnGestureListener. A ManagedOverlayer uses its own build-in GestureDetector that fires
>   events like:
>
> - onSingleTap(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
> - onDoubleTap(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
> - onLongPress(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
> - onZoom(ZoomEvent, ManagedOverlay) onScrolled(...)

Comment: Yeah, I tried to work with onTouchEvent but it was a lot to take in. I've just started working in the mapview-overlay-project and it's looking pretty good. I think it's my ticket to a more interactive map. Thank you for pointing me to that!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Happy coding. :)